# Passing php variable to jquery and from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<script>

    $(document).ready('click','#btnadd',AddCategoryForm: function(catId)
    {   
        //$('#addCategoryForm').load('./addCategory.php');
        alert('hi'+catId);

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("addCategoryForm1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        //xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?catId="+catId, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<input id="btnadd" type="button" value="Add Category" onClick="AddCategoryForm(<?php echo $catId ?>)">
```

my `jquery` is not running every time page is refreshed/resubmitted so i put it in
inline function with `document ready`.. but it can not pass the variable
which contain object which i am passing from `php`.

Comment: There's a syntax error by the way.

Comment: What do you mean passing from php?

Comment: if i use it directly by defining buttons click event,  click fucntion is not called while resubmitting the same page..

Comment: the catid variable passed to jquery function is php variable... and i want to pass it to other php file called addCategory.php

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that you forgot the ';' character?
It should look like this:

```
onClick="AddCategoryForm(<?php echo $catId; ?>)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#static_parent').on('click','#btnadd',function(){AddCategoryForm($(this).attr('data-katid'))});
    }

function AddCategoryForm(catId)
{
    //$('#addCategoryForm').load('./addCategory.php');
    alert('hi'+catId);

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("addCategoryForm1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    //xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?catId="+catId, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="static_parent">
    <input id="btnadd" type="button" value="Add Category" data-katid="<?php echo $catId; ?>">
</div>
```

You forgot script type
maybe try this aproach.
that is easier to change.
 i added on method because you havent specified if button is added dinamicaly to html - in this case you need to add wraper to dinamicaly created button that is static - thats why i added div with id static_parent

but if its simple static button then try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddCategoryForm(catId)
{
    //$('#addCategoryForm').load('./addCategory.php');
    alert('hi'+catId);

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("addCategoryForm1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    //xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "addCategory.php?catId="+catId, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>

<input id="btnadd" type="button" value="Add Category" onClick="AddCategoryForm(<?php echo $catId; ?>)">
```

Comment: now im reading question again and think maybe i misread a question.

Comment: why you need ready? do you think someone will click button before page is loaded?